# How to change Organization Owner

Tags: apex, soql, ownership, sharerecord

Is it possible to change the Company Information owner? I am facing an INACTIVE_OWNER_OR_USER error which is due to the owner being an inactive user.

[image]

Does not appear I can query for OwnerId either to simply do an update.
    SELECT Id,LanguageLocaleKey,Phone FROM Organization

Can this be done either via Apex or Salesforce Admin Settings?

Comment: When are you getting this error? On a specific action/workflow/etc?

Comment: From an Apex Job which is utilizing code from an installed package that is not visible. But the error code indicates that the owner of this record (created by) is inactive which is true. Looking for a way to change the owner to someone else.

Comment: I'm confused what you're looking for in Organization. It sounds like the apex job is running as an inactive user. Are you able to abort the job and re-run it as someone else?

Comment: There are many places in SFDC where automated operations may have been set up using an inactive User: scheduled reports/dashboards, email-to-case/other automated case operations, default workflow user, etc.  These are all defined in Setup. The Organization's CreatedById should never need to be changed nor can it be